# Restanglar. Catch response from request interceptor

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I need to set timeout to every Restangular request and cancel it if success response received. The question is how access response in request interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved it:

Service:

```
angular.module('mmn')
  .factory('serverTimeout', function($timeout, $rootScope) {

    var serverTimeout = {
      request: function(config) {
        config.timeout = $timeout(function() {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('event:serverTimeout');
        }, 30000);

        return config;
      },
      response: function(response) {
        $timeout.cancel(response.config.timeout);
        return response;
      }
    };
    return serverTimeout;
  });
```

App.config:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('serverTimeout');
```

App.run:

```
  //watch serverTimeout event
  $rootScope.$on('event:serverTimeout', function(){
    //your handler here
  });
```